# angular - rootscope broadcast on locationChangeStart not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm sending a $rootScope.$broadcast from my run function, on the $locationChangeStart event. In one of my controllers I've set a listener, but it doesn't get the event. Is the event broadcast too early in the page life-cycle? What's the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Can be anything. Better post your code.

Comment: Is your listener inside the controller that gets activated by the new state or the old State? If it's in the controller of the new state your broadcast gets probably sent before the new controller starts listening i guess...

Comment: What do you mean by old state and new state? I can definitely see it is a problem caused by event firing to early, because when I delay the broadcast of the event for 1 second using setTimeout, the event is received by the listener. But I don't want to set some arbitrary delay, I want to be sure my listener is ready. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What information does the controller need from your run function?

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the following Routes:

1. **Route:** /#/first, **View:** first.html, **Controller:** first-ctrl.js
2. **Route:** /#/second, **View:** second.html, **Controller:**
   second-ctrl.js

Now imagine you have a button on the first view that redirects your app to the second route where your second view with your second controller kicks in. And inside the second controller you have your listener that tries to catch your broadcast event.

So after you click on the button, the $locationChangeStart gets triggered and your app sends the broadcast. But the broadcast happens before the url changes and the second controller gets activated.

Your workaround with setTimeout works, because after the delay the url has already changed and the second controller was activated before you send the broadcast.

I don't know exactly what you try to do with that broadcast, but maybe you could try to use [$locationChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) instead?